# How to sell a financed car in California?

Tags: car, california, selling, financing, title

Hi I'm trying to sell a financed car. I have around 5k left to pay through Wells Fargo and and I'm selling the car for 10k. A few questions:

**Q1:** Do I still have to fill out a Bill of Sale and a Release of Liability of I'm financing the vehicle?

**Q2:** Are there any other paperworks I or the buyer need to fill out?

**Q3:** Also another question: Is this a safe and appropriate way to sell my car?

1. Receive the money from buyer into my bank account via wire transfer
2. Make sure money is confirmed in my account and then release the car to buyer
3. Pay off car to Wells Fargo (my financing company)
4. After Wells Fargo receives my payment, I will have Wells Fargo send the lien and title to the buyer directly
5. Seller and buyer handles everything with DMV

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Have you asked Wells Fargo what they would need to release the title?

Comment: @quid They said they just need the amount paid in full (may take a few business days to process the payment). Once they receive the full payment, they will release the title.